# OpenEXR header file not found

Tags: c++, openexr

I've built and install OpenEXR library to usr/local. However, when running g++ compiler on my header files that has

```
#include <ImfRgbaFile.h>
#include <ImfChannelList.h>
#include <ImfHeader.h>
#include <ImfOutputFile.h>
#include <ImfInputFile.h>
#include <ImfStandardAttributes.h>
#include <ImfArray.h>
```

These header files are not found. How do I get these to compile in my project?

Comment: What OS do you use? How did you install OpenEXR? What `g++` command did you use? What was the error message?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html `/usr/local` is not treated as a "default" location for things - it's a place for "manually installed things" so you'd need to add your include path manually.... I'm surprised the OpenEXR installation instructions don't mention this

Comment: Yes thank you! I was able to just do <openexr/xxx.h>